# Do something when width is exactly 800px

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to do something like this: when is exactly 800px, but does not work

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        if(windowWidth = 800){
            $('.content').removeClass('invisible');
            $('.desktopa').show();
            $('.lettera').show();
            $('.letterb').hide();
            $('.button').text('Menú');
            $('.menu').show();
        }
        else{
            $('.menu').hide();
        }
});
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this would be eeasier with CSS rules...

Comment: plus 1 for CSS media queries

Comment: It is almost impossible to exactly resize the screen to a given size - assuming that you are altering the width of the window by dragging it - this means that the user will  make it too small - say - 780px  then go the other way - say to 810px then 795px  then 802px then maybe 800px. Doing it this way means that each pass will have a single point that is correct within an incorrect range - as such the content / classes will confusingly fire at a single point and then revert at all other sizes - leading to confusion. Would suggest making it a broad enough range to allow a close enough value.

Answer (score 1):

`windowWidth = 800` is assigning the value of 800 to the `windowWidth` variable.

You need to use double (`==`, loose equality) or triple equals (`===`, strict equality) for comparison. See the MDN for [Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        if(windowWidth === 800){
            $('.content').removeClass('invisible');
            $('.desktopa').show();
            $('.lettera').show();
            $('.letterb').hide();
            $('.button').text('Menú');
            $('.menu').show();
        }
        else{
            $('.menu').hide();
        }
});
```

Comment: It does not suit for what i am asking for i want to use the 800px width as a break point and fire the conditions only at that point

Comment: this should work.. it says.. when the window is _EXACTLY_ 800 wide, do things.. `else` (aka. _at all other times_) do the other things

Comment: or are you asking so that things only happen when the page changes between being above and being below 800?

Comment: @DiegoCervantes, you're probably going to find that the `resize` event only triggers every few milliseconds, so if someone resizes too quickly, it will "skip" numbers.. can you explain in your question what exactly you're trying to do when a user resizes their window please